# dplyr syntax for most co-occurring terms

Tags: dplyr, dbplyr

I have a data frame with two columns; ids and groups. One id can be a member of multiple groups. I'm now looking for a dplyr way of iterating over each unique id and getting, say, the 10 most overlapping other ids in terms of which group they belong to. So, for each id get all groups it belongs to, then get all ids in those groups, group by id and rank by counts basically. This is in a database so I'd optimally like to use something compatible with dbplyr, but if I get a hint I can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without reproducible code, but this be along the lines of what you're looking for:

```
df = df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
summarise(COUNT = n()) %>%
arrange(desc(COUNT) %>%
head(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this. `gene` is `id` and `article` is `group`.

```
tbl(con, "article_gene_mentions") %>%
  inner_join(tbl(con, "article_gene_mentions") %>% rename(gene2 = gene), by = "article") %>%
  filter(gene != gene2) %>%
  group_by(gene, gene2) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = n, n = 10)
```